# Программа не заходит в цикл for (С++) Задача: Проверка строки на наличии 2-х точек и букв, можно только цифры и 1 точку

Tags: c++, циклы, for

Попытался написать программу для проверки строки на наличие 2-ой точки или любых символов. Допускается ввод только цифр. Программа почему-то не заходит в цикл for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    string str;
    int dot = 0;
    bool charTrue = false;

    cout << "Write\n";
    cin >> str;
    cout << str << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i++; i<=str.length()) {
        if (str[i] == '.') {
            dot += 1;
        }
        else if(str[i]!=0 || str[i]!=1 || str[i]!=2 || str[i]!=3 || str[i]!=4 || str[i]!=5 || str[i]!=6 || str[i]!=7 || str[i]!=8 || str[i]!=9) {
            charTrue = true;
        }
        if (charTrue == true || dot >= 2) {
            cout << "Содержится недопустимый символ или 2-ая точка по индексу " << i << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    if (charTrue == false || dot < 2) {
        cout << "Строка не содержит недопустимых символов! \nСтрока:" << str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нарушен порядок аргументов в цикле

```
 for (int i = 0; i++; i<=str.length())
```

Замените на

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
```

for (действие ***до начала*** цикла;     условие ***продолжения*** цикла;     действия ***в конце*** каждой итерации цикла)